# How can I set a footer in an android listview to dynamically stretch to the bottom?

Tags: android, listview, footer

I searched already but unfortunately found no real solution to this. I have added a footer to a listview with:

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null);
listview.addFooterView(footer);
```

The xml for the footer looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#ee222222"
>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Test Test Test"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

It does display a footer only as a single line

I change the number of rows in the list dynamically but I want the footer to always fill the rest of the listview if there are not enough items in it.

How can I do this?

Edit: I added an image, the left is how it is right now and the 2 on the right is what I want.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific, if possible, please add snap shot of how it is looks now, and how would u want it to look like, I can help you in this.

Comment: I added an image that explains it a little better.

Comment: @HardCoder, Are you get any answer, I have some things, Actually I have to add a progress bar in last item of ListView

Answer (score 0):

I can say the best solution can be for this problem is.

1) Create a XMl layout which must have hierarchy like this.

```
 <Liniear Layout>
  <ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
     <ListView>// add your list data here.

     <\ListView>
     <TextView><TextView>// for footer text

     <\LinearLayout>  
   <ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
```

Please let me kno if anything, I hope this approach will work as I tried it myself.

Comment: I am not quite certain, but do you mean that I shouldn't use the footer functions of the listview itself but use a scrollview instead to fake it? Or what is the scrollview for?

Comment: certainly if you want your UI look like what you want... else happy with what you are getting with footer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How can what you posted help me with my problem?

Comment: Its quite simple. dont use different xml layout for footer. I just want to say, have a layout which must have a listview and the textview.  Listview on top and textview below Listview. and moke both of them scrollable if you want textview to be below of last list item. or you can add text view at the bottom of the page, independent of listview size..

Comment: But I want the footer to be a part of the list that scrolls out of view if I want to and not just a simple textview at the bottom. I also want the footer to take up the remaining space of the listview if there are not enough elements in it and it cannot be scrolled. What you are suggesting is a mere textview at the bottom that is always visible.

Comment: no it wont be visible all the time, only visible at the list end,,